# Adding constraint in request in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, vapor

My url has all kind of longitude and latitude. But what I want is to perform the `Per` data that the distance is under 10000. How should I add a constraint to return only the data I want but not all.

```
func getlocation(){
            guard let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/pers") else {
                fatalError("URL is not defined!")
            }
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                do{
                    if let data = data {
                        let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([Per].self, from: data)
                       for value in result{
                            let latitude = value.latitude
                            let longitude = value.longitude
                            let mylatitude = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey:"mylatitude")
                            let mylongitude = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "mylongitude")
                        let mylocation = CLLocation(latitude: mylatitude, longitude: mylongitude)
                        let location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)
                        if location.distance(from: mylocation) < 10000 {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                              // self.per = result
                               print(location.distance(from: mylocation))
                               print(latitude!, longitude!)
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            print("error")
                            print(latitude!, longitude!)
                        }
                    }
                    }else{
                        print("no data")
    
                    }
                }catch(let error){
                    print("error: ", error.localizedDescription)
                }
    
            }.resume()
        }
```

server:
controller:

```
import Foundation
import Vapor
import Fluent
final class InformationController{
   func getall (_ req: Request) throws ->EventLoopFuture<[Pers]>{
        return Pers.query(on: req.db).all()
    }
}
```

routers:

```
func routes(_ app: Application) throws {
   app.get("pers",use:InformationController.getall)
}
```

model:

```
import Foundation
import Fluent
import Vapor
import FluentPostgresDriver


final class Pers:Model,Content{
    static let schema = "people"
    
    @ID(key: .id)
    var id:UUID?
    
    @Field(key: "姓名")
    var name: String
    
    @Field(key: "IG帳號")
    var account: String
    
    @Field(key: "頭像")
    var picture: String
    
    @Field(key: "年紀")
    var age: String
    
    @Field(key: "生日")
    var birth: String
    
    @Field(key:"緯度")
    var latitude: Double
    
    @Field(key:"經度")
    var longitude: Double
    
    @Field(key: "居住城市")
    var city: String
    
    @Field(key: "興趣")
    var hobby : String
    
    @Parent(key: "user_id")
    var user: User

    init(){}
    
    init(id:UUID?=nil, name:String, account:String, picture:String ,age:String, birth:String,latitude: Double, longitude: Double, city:String, hobby:String, userId:UUID){
        self.id=id
        self.name=name
        self.account=account
        self.picture=picture
        self.age=age
        self.birth=birth
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.city=city
        self.hobby=hobby
        self.$user.id=userId
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this about how to reduce the amount of data the API sends back?

Comment: @George kind of. I just want to get the data if it is under my constraint.

Comment: Ok, I see now. Most APIs usually have queries. For example, with something like Firestore, you would be able to query a collection of documents that match a certain criteria. I see your endpoint is on localhost (for whatever reason) - does it have a way to query the database?

Comment: @George hey I've added up my server on the article including the information needed in this request.

Comment: On the line `Pers.query(on: req.db).all()` you are just getting everything. I haven't used these technologies by the way, so I'm not certain, but I'd assume instead of `all()` there is some sort of query depending on a condition? You will have to look at the documentation for the related framework. I can't really help more than that since I've not used `Fluent`, `Vapor`, `FluentPostgresDriver` or anything.

Comment: @George ok, but thanks.